# Long list of similar rules

Tags: replacement, syntax, rule

Given the following:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h];

{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. {a -> 12, c -> 12, e -> 12, f -> 12}

(* {12, b, 12, d, 12, 12, g, h} *)
```

Is there a more elegant or shorter notation to replace multiple symbols with a similar value?

Comment: These kind of problems are best solved using the Map function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have a single rule using Alternatives (|)...

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. x : (a | c | e | f) -> 12
```

Furthermore you can construct the rule on the fly...

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. x : Alternatives@@{a, c, e, f} -> 12
```

As noted by @Kuba below there is no requirement for the pattern to have a name (x) so...

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. (a | c | e | f) -> 12
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. Alternatives @@ {a, c, e, f} -> 12
```

also work.

Comment: Now that was kind of alternative (no pun intended) I was hoping for. Thanks Ymareth.

Comment: There is no need to name those patterns with `x:`.

Comment: The second alternative maybe even more useful since you can use a part of the original list.

Comment: @MathLind But keep the pattern name if you want to use the symbols as arguments, ie. `x : (a | c | e | f) :> 12 x`.

Answer (score 5):

I like using `Thread` for this kind of rules

`{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. Thread[{a, c, e, f} -> Table[12, {4}]]`

As @kguler suggests there is no need having a `Table` and keeping track of the length of the list also for a single value.

So the following is better!

`{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} /. Thread[{a, c, e, f} -> 12]`

Comment: Simpler `Thread[{a, c, e, f} -> 12]` also works.

Comment: You are right! I see it's because of head `h` being a `List` by default on `Thread[{a,c,e,f}->11,h]`

Comment: @MathLind, i think it might be better if tchronis could update -- if he agrees to - his answer adding the alternative syntax for `Thread`.

Comment: Added @kugler 's syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You asked for "more elegant or shorter" and Ymareth gave you exactly that.  However it is worth noting that with long `Alternatives` this comes at a performance cost.  Please observe:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

set = Range[20000];

fn1[x_] := set /. (Alternatives @@ x -> -1)
fn2[x_] := set /. (Dispatch @ Thread[x -> -1])

BenchmarkPlot[{fn1, fn2}, RandomChoice[set, #] &, 2^Range[14]]
```

[image]

If you do not include the time taken by `Dispatch` to optimize the table the second method has an even larger advantage, which is applicable if the rules will be used more than once.

As a guideline if it is short enough to type using `a | b | c | . . .` you're fine, but if using `Alternatives @@` at least consider `Dispatch`.

---

Ymareth wrote:

> It would be interesting to know, if at extreme values of n, the gradients are the same; dispatch just has a much lower constant multiplier or dispatch's cost is growing slower regardless of n.

The complexity of `Thread` and `Dispatch` seems pretty consistent:

```
set = List @@ Range[5*^6]; (* unpacked *)

BenchmarkPlot[{Dispatch@Thread[# -> -1] &}, RandomChoice[set, #] &, 2^Range[22], 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 60]
```

[image]

The complexity of replacement itself however seems to increase with the number of rules:

```
set = List @@ Range[5*^6];  (* unpacked *)

BenchmarkPlot[{set /. # &}, Dispatch@Thread[# -> -1] &@RandomChoice[set, #] &, 
 2^Range[22], TimeConstraint -> 60]
```

[image]

Perhaps the constant-time floor is the cost to apply a single rule to the five million element list and it takes ~= 10^5 rules before the cost of checking that many rules rises above the floor.  I'll try to think of other ways to probe this behavior.

Comment: +1 for using Dispatch and the `BenchmarkPlot` tool. It seems that I have to quit the kernel and re-run when removing `Dispatch@` from fn2 (Even when I use `ClearAll[fn2]` before that. I suppose it has something to do with the internals of `BenchmarkPlot` ?

Comment: @tchronis Thanks for the vote.  `BenchmarkPlot` caches its results.  I believe using slightly different input values will force a fresh run; for example you could use `2^Range[14] - 1`.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the name of one function also does the trick. Interesting! But is there a way to clear the cache? Anyway probably there are a lot of questions to be asked in only a comment.

Comment: @tchronis I like questions or I wouldn't be on this site. ;-)  A bit of spelunking suggests that this should do it: ``Clear[GeneralUtilities`Benchmarking`PackagePrivate`$TimingCaches]``

Comment: It would be interesting to know, if at extreme values of n, the gradients are the same; dispatch just has a much lower constant multiplier or dispatch's cost is growing slower regardless of n.

Comment: @Ymareth Please see update.

Comment: Just saw this.  Interesting to know.  In the past I've found rule-based approaches suddenly fail-to-scale but that was so far in the past the underlying algorithms have most likely improved since.

Answer (score 0):

`MapAt` on alternatives pattern:

```
With[{
  list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h},
  sub = {a, c, e, f}},
 MapAt[f, list,
  Position[list, Alternatives @@ sub]]]
```

Replace f with `12&` for a constant-12 function.